# Hide Navigation On Scroll

Tags: javascript, navigation

I would like to hide a fixed navigation bar once the user scrolls to a certain point and then show the navigation as soon as the user scrolls up. I have been making adjustments to the following code but have not been able to make the navigation appear as soon as the user scrolls up. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
#navbar {
  font-family: "Lucas", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif, "Sans Serif", Icons /*!System*/; 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.5rem; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}
```

```
<script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (currentScrollPos < 1111) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0rem";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-8rem";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should check out Headroom.js it does what you've described with very little effort. There are a whole lot of minute details to consider if you want to do this yourself so a small (1.38kb) plugin will save you a ton of time unless you're looking to recreate the wheel, either way it might be helpful for you to check out the code and see what it's doing. [Here's the site](https://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/)

Comment: Thank you @JHeth!

But I would prefer to nail the solution with this small bit of script.